# imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap, imaplib

Code:
Been getting the error in title but I don't see issue here

```
def test():
     imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
     imap_user = 'email'
     imap_pass = 'pass'

     imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
     imap.login(imap_user, imap_pass)
     imap.select('"[Gmail]/All Mail"')
     message = imap.search(None, 'SUBJECT', "Verify your email")
     print(message)

test()
```

whats the problem here?

Comment: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools if you want to work with email instead read RFC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your subject needs to be in quotes, as passed to the server.  You are only quoting it for Python, but not for transmission.

You are sending `SEARCH SUBJECT verify your email` (which looks like three broken commands) rather than `SEARCH SUBJECT "Verify your email"`.

Try `imap.search(NONE, 'SUBJECT', '"Verify your email"')`

Note the double quotes inside your string.